# Is there any reason to check, if poll blocked at reading stderr?

Tags: c, polling, epoll

My poll is blocked at calling point at polling STDERR fd, it never returns, I don't know what causes it, is there any points can I check the reason?
My main.c seems work ok, I just paste it in case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <poll.h>

int main() {
    // pipe stdout and stderr.
    int filedes[2];
    int filedes_err[2];
    if (pipe(filedes) == -1) {
        exit(1);
    } 
    if (pipe(filedes_err) == -1) {
        exit(1);
    }

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        exit(1);
    }

    if (pid == 0) {
        while((dup2(filedes[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1) && (errno == EINTR))
            ;
        close(filedes[1]); 
        close(filedes[0]);

        while((dup2(filedes_err[1], STDERR_FILENO) == -1) && (errno == EINTR))
            ;
        close(filedes_err[1]);
        close(filedes_err[0]);

        execl("/a/private_script.sh","/a/private_script.sh", "argument", (char *)NULL); // run a sub script.
        perror("execl");
        _exit(1);
    }

    // parent gather stdout and stderr
    close(filedes[1]);
    close(filedes_err[1]);

    int out_finish = 0;
    int err_finish = 0;
    for (;;) {
        struct pollfd fds[2];
        int i;
        int nfds = 0;

        if(!out_finish) {
            fds[nfds].fd = filedes[0];
            fds[nfds].events = POLLIN;
            fds[nfds].revents = 0; // return events.
            nfds++;
        }

        if(!err_finish) {
            fds[nfds].fd = filedes_err[0];
            fds[nfds].events = POLLIN;
            fds[nfds].revents = 0; // return events.
            nfds++;
        }

        if(nfds == 0) {
            break;
        }

        if (poll(fds, nfds, -1) < 0) {
            if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            perror("poll");
            goto cleanup;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < nfds; i++) {
            if (fds[i].revents & (POLLIN | POLLHUP | POLLERR)) {
                char buf[1024];
                int count;
                count = read(fds[i].fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
                if (count < 0) {
                    if (errno != EINTR &&
                        errno != EAGAIN) {
                            perror("read");
                            goto cleanup;
                        }
                } else if (count == 0) {
                    if(fds[i].fd == filedes[0]) {
                        out_finish = 1;
                        printf("out finish\n");
                    } else {
                        err_finish = 1;
                        printf("err finish\n");
                    }
                } else {
                  if(fds[i].fd = filedes[0]) {
                       buf[count]='\0';
                       printf("'stdout:%s'\n", buf, count);
                  } else {
                       printf("'stderr:%s'\n", buf, count);
                  }
                }
            }
        }
    }
cleanup:
    close(filedes[0]);
    close(filedes_err[0]);
    wait(NULL);
}
```

PLUS: script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# $1 timeout in seconds
# $2 command
timeout() {
        time=$1
        shift
        # start the command in a subshell to avoid problem with pipes
        # (spawn accepts one command)                            -noecho 
        command="/bin/sh -c \"$*\""
        expect -c "set echo \"-noecho\";set timeout $time; spawn -noecho $command; expect timeout { exit 1 } eof { exit 0 }"
        if [ $? = 1 ] ; then
            echo "timeout after ${time} seconds"
            exit 1
        fi

}

timeout 60 qemu-nbd --cache=none --aio=native  -c /dev/nbd0 a_remote.conf
```

It is blocked at `poll(fds, nfds, -1) < 0` after finish reading stdout.
I guess it is the problem of my private script, because if I replace other normal simple script, it works. I want to ask how could I check the reasons that cause poll blocked at polling STDERR?

Comment: That's a big ass main .. Consider cleaning your code a little bit

Comment: So many gotos......[Avoid using goto in code](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/programming-with-reason-why-is-goto-bad/228200966)

Comment: `buf[count]='\0'` will overwrite memory if `read(fds[i].fd, buf, sizeof(buf));` fills `buf`.

Comment: the poll probably works properly... you should post your script in another question and ask why it doesn't give the output you want

Comment: @ShlomiAgiv I am trying. I haven't figured what which part of code caused the problem, it's hard to separate the most important part to a simple script.

Comment: 1) the code is missing several header files, amongst them are: `#include <sys/types.h>`  `#include <sys/wait.h>`   2) Some of the `printf()` statements have a mismatch between the number of format specifiers and the number of arguments.  3) some of the statements are missing parens, resulting in incorrect compiler results.  4) some statements like: `if(fds[i].fd = filedes[0])` are actually assignments rather than comparisons.  I.E. `=` should be `==`.  Strongly suggest when compiling to enable all warnings and fix those warnings.  (for gcc at a minimum use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`)

Comment: the code is missing the header file to define a `pid_t`  I.E. #include <unistd.h>

Comment: there is a world of difference between exiting a program with `exit()` and `_exit()`  (read the man pages)  suggest the code be consistent and for various reasons, `exit()` is the better choice.  After any files are successfully opened or memory allocated, etc.  always close those files, free() that memory before calling `exit()`

Comment: there are a number of statements that `goto cleanup;`  However, the code after the label `cleanup:` does not cleanly exit the main() function.  and `wait(NULL);`  could wait forever of there is no child process.

Comment: after the first successful call to `pipe()`, then every call after that, that fails, need to close each of the 'fd's from the first call to pipe().  similar considerations (calls to close) for all the open files needs to be performed in the call to `fork()` fails.   etc etc

Comment: @user3629249 THX!! I will check those mistakes.

Comment: @Shlomi Agiv , I found the problem causing that, and ask another question, refer to :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32548232/why-expect-make-process-open-its-stderr